# How to make certain fields in an Access table directly reference another table's fields

Tags: ms-access

Hi I'm trying to do something very simple but I'm new to using Access.
I'm trying to do the Access equivalent of this formula in Excel (=Sheet1!A1); the cell in Sheet2 is to reference the cell in Sheet1 and this formular continues downward respective to the referenced sheet.

So I have a master table in Access that is being populated with a form.  I have two other tables which need to be populated in a specific order with respective data from the master table that is being created with a form.

Is there a simple way to just get a certain field from either of my other two tables to duplicate a specific field from the master table, in the same order.

I've searched this and tried a few things with "Relationship" table but I couldn't get it to work.  Some message about my fields not being the same width or the fact I don't really want a primary key in the mastertable as I don't like how it renumbers things with gaps when something is deleted.

There must be a simple way to say "Hey, these two tables have the same header.  Whatever this table has, duplicate it exactly over in the other table."  The two tables I want referencing the master table have the headers of the master table split between them and in different orders.

Thanks

Comment: There's no simple way of doing that, since it's not a native function of ms-access. Dynamic sheets should be done in excel, or maybe keep data in access, and query it from excel.

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up using a query in the end but was disappointed there is no dynamic ref.